# Trying to build ScadaBR in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to build ScadaBR which is basically written in Java ([http://www.scadabr.com.br/])[1](http://www.scadabr.com.br/) . I have the project imported and all the dependencies are met. Inspite of this when I right and say run on server it throws the following error:

```
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ScadaBR' did not find a matching property.
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2104 ms
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Aug 01, 2013 1:25:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ScadaBR]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ScadaBR]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/serotonin/ShouldNeverHappenException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796)
```

What is the issue. Could someone give me a pointer as I kind of lost right now.

Answer (score -1):

We do not provide the seroUtils.jar lib. At least no in our repository. If you´d like to know more about this discussion, check this link out.
http://www.scadabr.org.br/?q=node/885

Regards,